# How to store query results in a variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to store the results of a MySql query into a variable so that I can output the result as part of a sentence.

The query is as follows:

```
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select count(*) from customerdetails";
conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have read other forums and they have spoken about a method using "addwithvalue" however this hasnt been successful when I have used it, and the query result hasn't been outputted.

Comment: Look up how to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` if you simply want a `COUNT` - meaning a single value instead of a set of results.

Comment: 4 hours old -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866499

Answer (score 2):

[`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) is used for doing any insert, updates or delete operations only.

**ExecuteNonQuery :**

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

For selecting data you need to use [`ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx) which will read the data from the table in a sequential way.

**ExecuteReader :**

> Sends the **CommandText** to the Connection and builds a **SqlDataReader**.

So you will have to write it like:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int rowsCount = 0;
if(reader.Read())
{
   rowsCount = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, when this is done how would I convert the variable to a string? I have tried using .ToString however this has given me an error saying "Cannot convert method group "ToString" to non-delegate type int

Comment: @JoshDaniel in c# you call a method by using `()`. So use, `ToString();`, not `ToString;`

Comment: `ExecuteReader` is overkill here. For a single `count(*)`, `ExecuteScalar` suffices, and with less code and disposable-management to boot.